# SQL Join on value a otherwise value b

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two tables which I want to join in a certain way.

Table Resource:

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 |
| 2 | 2345 |

Table Options:

| articleId | typeId | optionKey |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 1 |
| 1 | 2345 | 5 |
| 2 | 2345 | 5 |

What I basically want to achieve is getting all articleId's with optionKey 1. If optionKey 1 doesn't exist it should look for optionKey 5. There may also be situations that neither 1 or 5 exist, resulting in the following desired table:

| articleId | typeId | optionKey |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 1 |
| 2 | 2345 | 5 |

I'm already using a very specific query in an SQL view for our SAP system. It does work in a way, the only thing is that it still returns articleId's for both 1 and 5 if they both exist.

```
select
        resource."articleId",
        COALESCE(imageTypeChoice1."optionKey",imageTypeChoice5."optionKey") as "imageTypeOptionId"
from "resource" as resource
left join "Options" as imageTypeChoice1 on resource."type" = imageTypeChoice1."id" AND imageTypeChoice1."optionKey" = '1'
left join "Options" as imageTypeChoice5 on resource."type" = imageTypeChoice5."id" AND imageTypeChoice5."optionKey" = '5'
where (imageTypeChoice1."optionKey" IS NOT NULL OR imageTypeChoice5."optionKey" IS NOT NULL)
```

Preferably we would like to do this without subquery's.

Comment: What platform? Why the arbitrary restriction on subqueries? Also, you example doesn't show the scenario where neither 1 nor 5 exist.

Comment: If an option doesn't exist should there be a row returned with a default, or no row, ie an inner join?

Comment: There should be no row, like an inner join

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you need, given just the sample data provided, is to aggregate your options before joining.

```
select r.Id articleId, r.type, o.optionKey
from resource r
join (
    select articleid,  Min(optionkey) optionkey
    from options
    group by articleid
)o on o.articleId = r.id
```